# Can computed properties be used in routing dynamic segment?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-old-router

I need to use two computed properties in the url of my app, but when make the transition they say undefined.

Here is my code:

```
App.PostController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    updated_at: null,
    year: function() {            
        var updated_at = this.get('updated_at');
        return moment(updated_at).format('YYYY');
    }.property().cacheable(),
    month: function() {
        var updated_at = this.get('updated_at');
        return moment(updated_at).format('MM');
    }.property().cacheable()
});

App.Router = Ember.Router.extend({
    location: 'history',
    //enableLogging: true,
    root: Ember.Route.extend({
        showPosts: Ember.State.transitionTo('posts'),
        posts: Ember.Route.extend({
            route: '/',
            posts: Ember.Route.extend({
                route: '/',
                showPost: Ember.State.transitionTo('post'),
                connectOutlets: function(router) {
                    router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('posts');
                }
            }),
            post: Ember.Route.extend({
                route: '/:year/:month/:slug',
                connectOutlets: function(router, post) {
                    router.get('applicationController').connectOutlet('post', post);
                }
            })
        })
    })
});
```

When a click to a post, the url look like this: `/undefined/undefined/this-is-a-slug`

This can be done?, If not, you can achieve otherwise?.

Thanks.

Comment: Does it work if you define these computed properties in the Post Model ?

Comment: Have you tried using `serialize` and `deserialize` in your route? Take a look at [this code](https://github.com/MilkyWayJoe/hello-ember-router/blob/master/HelloEmberRouter/Scripts/app.js), maybe it helps. Look into the contact `edit` and `details` routes (lines 355 to 406)

Comment: @sly7_7 Computer properties are in the Post Model, PostController extend from ObjetcController it's the same thing.

Comment: I don't think it's the same thing, as here the context is not the PostController, but a Post instance. So `year` and `month` defined in the PostController, are not in the post.

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe It works, thanks. Now i have to synchronize the serialize and deserialze when enter in the post url.